# Python sqlite connection.fetchone() returns none when their is data in the database

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I am using the following code:

```
def getDatabase():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    connection = conn.cursor()
    connection.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(CK, CSK, ATK, ATSK, DAK)''')
    conn.commit()
    row = connection.fetchone()
    print(row)
    if row:
        print("Database Has  Rows")
        ShowOptionScreen()

    else:
        print("Database Has No Rows")
        getKEYSfromuser()
```

I use this function to check if the table exists and if it does check if their is data in the table - it if not I call this function to save the users input into the table:

```
def getKEYSfromuser():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    global auth
    global userInputKeys 
    DisplayUserKeyInput = prompt(userInputKeys, style=style) 
    json_str = json.dumps(DisplayUserKeyInput)
    resp = json.loads(json_str) 
    a = resp['Consumer Key']
    b =  resp['Consumer Secret Key']
    c =  resp['Access Token Key']
    d = resp['Access Token Secret Key']
    auth = resp['Discord Auth key']
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    connection = conn.cursor()
    connection.execute("INSERT INTO data (CK, CSK, ATK, ATSK, DAK) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(str(a), str(b), str(c), str(d), str(auth)))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    apilogin(a,b,c,d)
    ShowOptionScreen()
```

However in the first function when their are rows in the database `row = connection.fetchone()` returns a value of none. How can i solve this?

But am I even saving the data with the function I cant tell please can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to query it.

Comment: @superbrain I have just updated the question to contain more info on my problem where do I need to add the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to add `connection.execute("select * from data")`

Here is the correct code

```py
def getDatabase():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    connection = conn.cursor()
    connection.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(CK, CSK, ATK, ATSK, DAK)''')
    conn.commit()
    connection.execute("select * from data")#you forgot to add this
    row = connection.fetchone()
    print(row)
    if row:
        print("Database Has  Rows")
        #ShowOptionScreen()

    else:
        print("Database Has No Rows")
        #getKEYSfromuser()
```